# Counting "pairic" multisets

Tags: combinatorics

**Definition 0.** Whenever $S$ is a finite set, define that a multiset of $S$ is a function $\mathbb{N} \leftarrow S$.

**Definition 1.** By an unordered pair of elements of $S$, I mean a multiset $A$ of $S$ that returns $0$ at all but two (distinct) elements of $S,$ at which $A$ returns $1$.

Obviously, the multisets of $S$ form an abelian monoid with respect to addition.

**Definition 2.** Call a multiset of $S$ *pairic* iff it is an element of the submonoid generated by the unordered pairs of elements of $S$.

> **Question.** Let $b$ and $k$ denote natural numbers (for "bound" and "cardinality" respectively). Suppose $S$ is a set with cardinality $k$. How many pairic multisets of $S$ are bounded by $b$?

Call the number we're trying to find $f(b,k)$.

A couple of observations:

Firstly, $f(b,k) \leq b^k$.

Secondly, the $b=1$ case is easy:

$$f(1,k) = \sum_{n\leq k, \,n\, \mbox{Even}} \binom{k}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer**, but it recasts the question in a way that may perhaps prove helpful. Let $\varphi:S\to\Bbb N$ be a multiset. Then $\varphi$ is pairic iff there is a family $E$ of $2$-element subsets of $S$ such that $G=\langle S,E\rangle$ is a graph, and $\varphi(s)=\deg_Gs$ for each $s\in S$. Conversely, if $G=\langle S,E\rangle$ is a graph without loops, the function $\deg_G:S\to\Bbb N$ is a pairic multiset.

Now suppose that $|S|=k$. A sequence $\langle d_1,\ldots,d_k\rangle$ such that $d_1\ge d_2\ge\ldots\ge d_k\ge 0$ is a degree sequence for a graph $G=\langle S,E\rangle$ without loops iff $\sum_{i=1}^kd_i$ is even, and $d_1\le\sum_{i=2}^kd_i$. Necessity is obvious. Sufficiency can be proved by induction on $\sum_{i=1}^kd_i$:

> Let the vertices be $v_1,\ldots,v_k$, where $\deg_Gv_i=d_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$. If $d_1=\sum_{i=1}^kd_i$, just put $d_i$ edges from $v_1$ to $v_i$ for $i=2,\ldots,k$. Otherwise, the fact that the sum of the degrees is even ensures that $d_1\le\sum_{i=2}^kd_i-2=\sum_{i=2}^{k-2}d_i+(d_{k-1}-1)+(d_k-1)$. Apply the induction hypothesis to the degree sequence $\langle d_1,\ldots,d_{k-2},d_{k-1}-1,d_k-1\rangle$, then add an edge between $v_{k-1}$ and $v_k$.

The question can now be rephrased as follows. Given $k$ and $b$, how many functions $\varphi:[k]\to\Bbb N$ are there such that

- $\sum_{i\in[k]}\varphi(i)$ is even, and
- $\varphi(i)\le\min\left\{b,\frac12\sum_{j\in[k]}\varphi(j)\right\}$ for each $i\in[k]$.

> Equivalently, how many ways are there to distribute an even number of indistinguishable stones amonsgst $k$ distinguishable jars so that no jar receives more than $b$ stones, and no jar receives more than half of the stones?

Comment: @goblin: You're welcome! I'm still thinking about the actual problem, but it's a bit messy.